# Searchable Markers on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to setup a situation where I post 5 different markers on a Google map. Next to the map is a search bar, when I search for the title of one of the markers, it appears on the map while the other four disappear.

Does anyone have an example of this by chance? Sorry for the lack of technicality.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement, which I solved by adding a dropdown list to the top of the map, where users could select a marker to pan to.

Here is a quick and dirty way of doing this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gTnCU/2/